# usage of theme_more_link in zen template.php

Tags: 7, theming

I have tried to change the text in the 'Read more' link by putting:

```
function myzen_more_link($url, $title) {
  watchdog("template.php","myzen_more_link");
  return '<div class="more-link">' . 
    t('<a href="@link" title="@title">( more ... )</a>', 
    array('@link' => check_url($url), 
    '@title' => $title)) . '</div>';
}
```

In the template.php in my zen subtheme folder but it does not appear to work.

Almost all of the discussions I have seen about formatting the "more_link" concentrate on its placement.  Can anyone tell me why this theme override does not take effect?

Comment: When possible, avoid adding HTML tags in a string passed to `t()`. In your case, the `<a>` tag is at the beginning of the string, and it doesn't contain anything that needs to be translated.

Comment: This is actually copied directly from the theme.inc function theme_more_link.  (line 1600)

Answer (score 1):

What you have done should work. Have you remembered to clear cache?

Comment: Yes.  It would useful to know how to trace this.  The function is never called.  The only way I could change the value was to modify the theme.inc file.

Comment: It should work, as described in [Beginners guide to overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/223440). To work, `myzen` must be the theme's base prefix, though; if the base prefix is `myzen_theme` and the function name is `myzen_more_link()`, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Latest version of these functions are at [link](http://pastebin.com/K2HztnFQ)

Comment: Please note that this answer is incorrect as cache was cleared.

Answer (score 0):

First you should to declare onw theme element 'more_link'

```
function mymodule_theme(){
  return array(
    'more_link' => array(
      'arguments' => array('url' => NULL, 'title' => NULL)
    )
  );
}

function mymodule_more_link($url, $title) {
  watchdog("template.php","myzen_more_link");
  return '<div class="more-link">' . 
    t('<a href="@link" title="@title">( more ... )</a>', 
    array('@link' => check_url($url), 
    '@title' => $title)) . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is not the whole story for the zen theme.  I note above that this is the solution for a **module** doing theming; however, the zen sub-theme item - Implementation of HOOK_theme has a comment: // @TODO: Needs detailed comments. Patches welcome!

Comment: Continuing -- In that function we have: `function myzen_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks = zen_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);` to which I added `$hooks['more_link'] = array( 'arguments' => array('url' => NULL, 'title' => NULL) );`

Comment: The function zen_theme returns an empty array so it clearly is not using this mechanism for its own example of sub-theming - zen_breadcrumb.  I am still missing something obvious here, needless to say, my theme function myzen_more_link is never called.